# Translate paragraph in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to translate a Paragraph from english to my local language which I have written the code as:

```
def translate(inputvalue):
//inputvalue is an array of english paragraphs
        try:
            translatedData = []
            trans = Translator()
            for i in inputvalue:
                sentence = re.sub(r'(?<=[.,])(?=[^\s])', r' ', i)
                //adding space where there is no space after , or ,
                t = trans.translate(sentence, src='en', dest = 'ur')
                //translating from english to my local language urdu
                translatedData.append(t.text)
                //appending data in translatedData array    
            DisplayOutput.output(translatedData)
            //finally calling DisplayOutput function to print translated data
```

The problem I am facing here is that my local language begins writing from [Right side]
and **googletrans** is not giving proper output. It puts **periods** ,**commas**, **untranslated words** at the beginning or at the end for example:

```
I am 6 years old. I love to draw cartoons, animals, and plants. I do not have ADHD.
```

it would translate this sentence as:

```
میری عمر 6 سال ہے،. مجھے کارٹون جانور اور پودے کھینچنا پسند ہےمجھے ADHD 6نہیں ہے.
```

As you can observe it could not translate ADHD as it is just an abbreviation it puts that at the beginning of the sentence and same goes for periods and numbers and commas.

How should I translate it so that it does not conflict like that.

If putting the sentence in another array like:

```
['I am', '6', 'years old', '.', 'I love to draw cartoons',',', 'animals',',', 'and plants','.', 'I do not have', 'ADHD','.']
```

I have no idea how to achieve this type of array but I believe it can solve the problem.
As I can translate only the parts that has English words and then appending the list in a string.

Kindly Help me generate this type of array or any other solution

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "I am 6 years old. I love to draw cartoons, animals, and plants. I do not have ADHD."

arr = []

substring = ""
alpha = None
for char in string:
    if char.isalpha() or char == " ": alpha = True
    else: alpha = False
    if substring.replace(" ","").isalpha():
        if alpha:
            substring += char
        else:
            arr.append(substring)
            substring = char
    else:
        if alpha:
            arr.append(substring)
            substring = char

while " " in arr: arr.remove(" ")
while "" in arr: arr.remove("")

print(arr)
```

Loop through each character in the string, then check if it is a letter or not a letter with ".isalpha()". Then depending on the conditions of the current substring, you append to it or create a new one.

Comment: Thanks but it also splits apostrophe. Can you make it as it won't split apostrophe as well